# How do you call one future and then pass that return value into another future to run?

Tags: flutter, future

I am trying to take a picture with my Android camera, upload that picture to Google Firebase Storage, get the downloadable URL of that image on Storage, and update the user's photo feed on Firestore. If I only call takeImage() it takes the image and uploads successfully to storage. If I call _uploadImage with a dummy image url, it correctly updates the feed. But I cannot get the result of takeImage to pass as a parameter to _uploadImage().

```
void takeAndSave() async {
              url = await takeImage();
              _uploadImage(url);


          }


Future<String> takeImage() async {
    // open camera
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    // save image to temp storage
    final String fileName = "${Random().nextInt(10000)}.jpg";

    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // AppData folder path
    String appDocPath = directory.path;



    // copy image to path
    File savedImage = await image.copy('$appDocPath/' + fileName);

    // upload file to Firebase Storage
    final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    final StorageUploadTask task = ref.putFile(savedImage);
    String downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    url = downloadURL;
    //    _image = image;

    return downloadURL;
}



Future<void> _uploadImage(String url) async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await widget.auth.currentUser();
    String uid = user.uid;
    print('uid = ' + uid);
    print(url);
      // upload URL to Firebase Firestore Cloud Storage

      Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
        DocumentReference _newPhoto = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid);

        await _newPhoto.collection('cards').add({"url" : url});

      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To chain future tasks:** means if we have two future tasks and second is dependent upon result of first response then we can use "`Future.wait()`". In the below example i have created two methods with async keyword that will fetch data from server and i want to execute "fetchPostAgain()" method after the response of first "fetchPost()" then i can use "Future.wait()".

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/models/Post.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  FetchFirstPost getFirstPost;
  String myString = "Loading...";

  void _takeImage() {
    Future.wait([fetchPost()]).then((FutureOr) => {
        fetchPostAgain()
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Text(myString),
              ),

              RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Run Future"),
                    onPressed: _takeImage,
                          ),
              ],
          ),
          /*child: CallApiDemo(),*/
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
    final Completer completer = Completer();
    final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
    log('data: ' + response .statusCode.toString());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      setState(() {
        myString = response.body;
      });
      return postFromJson(response.body);
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }

  Future<Post> fetchPostAgain() async{
    final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
    log('GOT SECOND RESPONSE');
    log('data: ' + response .statusCode.toString());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        myString = myString + "\n\n\nAGAIN\n\n\n" + response.body;
      });
      return postFromJson(response.body);
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think to check for Exceptions because I could see that the file uploaded correctly to the database, but I was not getting the correct response back as to the file's URL which was what I wanted to pass on. Setting the exception checking helped me debug that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, it should work properly, but there could be a chance that your takeImage() method is returning an exception. Try catching that exception and see if it helps.

Below is referenced from https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#async-await

If a Future-returning function completes with an error, you probably want to capture that error. Async functions can handle errors using try-catch:

```
Future<String> takeImage() async {
  try {
    // Your code
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle error...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think to do a try-catch because I could see that the file uploaded correctly to the database, but I was not getting the correct response back as to the file's URL which was what I wanted to pass on. Setting the error checking helped me debug that. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad I could help. Did you upvote and accept the other answer instead? :P